# Efficiently Sharing Resources and Components Between Vite Applications

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite, bundles

Problem:

I'm working on a multi-application project using Vite. Each application (e.g., login, home, shared) has some components and resources (images, fonts) that need to be shared across the others. My current setup builds each application into a separate subfolder within the dist directory. I'm looking for the most effective approach to share resources and components without duplicating code or assets.

Desired Outcome:

I want to achieve code reusability and efficient resource management while maintaining the separate build structure for each application.

Comment: For resources, it's as simple as keeping them in public/ . It's unknown what's multi-app in your case. Is it https://vitejs.dev/guide/build#multi-page-app ?